# How to not double print when matching multiple words in a sentence

Tags: python, string, list, match

Say we have the following sentence and words to match

```
sentences = ['There are three apples and oranges in the fridge.', 'I forgot the milk.']
wordsMatch = ['apples', 'bananas', 'fridge']
```

How to iterate through the sentences and print them if there is a match without double / triple printing it if it finds more than 1 matches?

For instance, the following code will print the first sentence twice because it finds apples and fridge:

```
matchedSentences = [sentence for sentence in sentences for word in wordsMatch if word in sentence]

# output: ['There are three apples and oranges in the fridge.', 'There are three apples and oranges in the fridge.']
```

What solution would be most appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
output = [
    sentence 
    for sentence in sentences 
    if any(word in sentence for word in wordsMatch)
]
```

The [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function returns `True` as soon as one of the elements in the iterable provided is `True`. Therefore we can simply loop over the `sentences` and check that *any* of the words is in a sentence.

**PS:**

I am assuming that the solution should be case-sensitive. If not, you can adjust the `word in sentence`-check accordingly:

```py
output = [
    sentence
    for sentence in sentences
    if any(word.lower() in sentence.lower() for word in wordsMatch)
]
```

**PPS: (just for fun)**

Here is how to do it in-place with the `sentences` list:

```py
removed = 0
for i, sentence in enumerate(reversed(sentences), start=1):
    if not any(word in sentence for word in wordsMatch):
        del sentences[-i + removed]
        removed += 1
```

Comment: I had applied text cleaning such as punctuation removal, text lowering and the sorts. Thank you for this answer and for adding the .lower() for future readers. 

I was wondering, how would we apply this if we wanted to print all sentences that don't match? What is the opposite of any()?  none()? We would not be able to use the same logic due to iterating in if any(word in sentence for word NOT IN wordsMatch).

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus The opposite of `any(...)` is `not any(...)` :-) See my _PPS_

Comment: I commented prematurely. Thank you for your input! It was very insightful.